# How to take only time from the user in @Temporal

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently I am using following code to take date as a input from user

```
@NotBlank
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="start_time")
private Date start;
```

But i want to enter only time from the user not date.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Consider using LocalTime if your project is in Java 8 and using Hibernate 5.1 or newer. The old java.util.Date class will always be a source of problems.

Answer (score 0):

If your column's datatype in your database is "time", it will save only the time data even if it's a Date object. And later you will get your data like "1970-01-01 hh:mm:ss" from database.

If your inputs are only hour, minutes, seconds, use the setHours(), setMinutes(), setSeconds() method

I think it is because of the easy way to get current time with **new Date()** and Date obj can also manage the time zone problem. It's just my opinion :D